# Is there a way to use a pom.xml file to update spark configuration?

Tags: bigdata, apache-spark, scala

I am trying to update my spark configuration to solve some dependency problems.

[This](https://github.com/caroljmcdonald/spark-ml-kmeans-uber/blob/master/pom.xml) pom.xml file seems to be useful for this purpose.

I am using a [spark docker image](https://github.com/big-data-europe/docker-spark).

```
ls /spark/conf
```

Gives:

```
docker.properties.template    slaves.template
fairscheduler.xml.template    spark-defaults.conf.template
log4j.properties.template     spark-env.sh.template
metrics.properties.template
```

I've searched pom.xml in the container by using `find / -name "pom.xml"` and got nothing.

Is there a way to use a pom.xml file to update spark configuration?